# How do I convert the following SQL Statement to an Update Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How do I convert the following SQL Statement to an Update statement:

```
select
    * 
from
    BomStructure BS
where
    Component = '322058-000000'
    and
    exists
    (
        select
            1
        from
            BomStructure
        where
            ParentPart = BS.ParentPart
            and
            Component = '322123-301200'
    );
```

I want to

```
update
    BomStructure BS
set
    StructureOffDate = '2019-09-30'
where 
    Component = '322058-000000'
    and
    exists
    (
        select
            1
        from
            BomStructure
        where
            ParentPart = BS.ParentPart
            and
            Component = '322123-301200'
    );
```

But my syntax above is incorrect. Please assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what you are looking for is to update the date of all the components "322058-000000" whose parent part also has the component "322123-301200". If so, the following query should do the trick:

```
update BomStructure
set StructureOffDate = '2019-09-30'
where Component='322058-000000' and Parentpart in (select distinct Parentpart from BomStructure where Component = '322123-301200')
```

Comment: Thank you that is exactly what I wanted :).

Answer (score 1):

I think you want :

```
update bs
      set bs.StructureOffDate = '2019-09-30'
from BomStructure bs
where exists (select 1 
              from BomStructure bs1
              where bs1.ParentPart = bs.ParentPart and bs1.Component = '322123-301200'
             );
```

Your outer filter will update only rows where as `Component = '322123-301200'`, but as per query you looks like you want update `ParentPart` in which it has `Component = '322123-301200'`